# Custom command with \ensuremath within \textbf

Tags: math-mode, bold, boldmath

I have created a custom command to help me with scientific number notation:

```
\newcommand{\E}[1]{\ensuremath{\cdot 10^{#1}}}
```

The command works OK, but now I have a need to bold some of the numbers and the result is the following:

[image]

The code produced the image above is the following:

```
-4,25\E{-6}
\textbf{-1,73\E{-6}}
```

As you can see, the exponent part is *not* bolded.

My question is simple: how to bold the whole number?

Comment: Isn't the usage of `siunitx` easier here?

Comment: `\newcommand{\E}[1]{\boldmath\ensuremath{\cdot 10^{#1}}\unboldmath}`... but not recommended

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I don't want to bold all the numbers, just the ones within `\textbf`. If there is not an easy way to do this, then I will look into `siunitx`.

Comment: Actually, `siunitx` is the easiest way, in my point of view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use the `siunitx` package and the `detect-weight` setting for is, with `\num{...}` as typesetter.

If the `exponent-product` key is omitted, the default `x` style for numbers is usesd.

The `d-6` style will print as `10^{-6}` then.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[detect-weight,mode=text,copy-decimal-marker=true,exponent-product=\cdot]{siunitx}

\begin{document}


\num{-1,73d-6}

\textbf{\num{-1,73d-6}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a specific command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\anum}[2][n]{%
  \mbox{%
    \mathcode`,=\numexpr\mathcode`,-"6000
    \if#1b\boldmath\fi
    $#2$%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\E}[1]{\cdot10^{#1}}

\begin{document}

\anum{-4,25\E{-6}}

\anum[b]{-1,73\E{-6}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the minus sign is a real minus and not a hyphen; also the comma leaves no unwanted space.